# How do i parallelize this simple for loop?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to precompute a (symmetric) distance matrix to use it later for clustering with dbscan.

However already for a tiny 51x51 test matrix takes ~10min to calculate with the actual datasets i want to cluster being on the order of >2000 points which would take upwards of 10 days to compute.

Due to that i want to parallelize this if possible.

Currently the matrix is being build like this:

```
            precomputed = np.zeros((len(train_features), len(train_features)))
            for i in range(len(train_features)):
                logging.info(i)
                for j in range(i + 1, len(train_features)):
                    precomputed[i][j] = self.trajectory_distance(
                        train_features[i], train_features[j], "geodesic"
                    )
                    precomputed[j][i] = precomputed[i][j]
```

I feel like this should be easily be parallelized using multiprocessing.pool but i seem to have a mental block right now.

Comment: why not use the scipy solution? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html

Comment: It seems that `trajectory_distance` is not your grampa's distance.

Comment: I have a custom distance function which this does not seem to allow.